# How to give three different color scheme (cmap value) to sklearn heatmap confusion matrix

Tags: scikit-learn, data-visualization, heatmap, colorbar, confusion-matrix

I have a 3* 3 confusion matrix (multilabel classification), I want to to give each row a different color(so that each class can be easily distinguished based on color) How can I do this using sklearn heatmap function?

```
data=confusion_matrix(dt['Actual'], dt['Prediction'])
sns.heatmap(data,annot=True,cmap='BuGn',cbar= False)
```

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried? Please post the relevant part of your code.

Comment: @BLimitless edited. This is a 2*2 matrix, I am also trying for 3*3 matrix, I want to change color based on rows.

Comment: Thanks for updating, now the community should be able to help!